# Unable to add a image logo with the email in Jhipster for user registration

Tags: jakarta-mail, thymeleaf, html-email, jhipster, jhipster-registry

In my Jhipster Application when I create new user it sends email for reset password, users getting email but I want to display one image in that email so it looks good

I have written fillowing line in ActivationEmail.html to add image but When user didn't get image in email.

```
<img th:src="@{|${https://crunchbase-production-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/c_lpad,h_256,w_256,f_auto,q_auto:eco/v1484233225}/vexdy5hgzgljw17nums1.png|}" alt="Mountain View" style="width:150px;height:100px"></img>
```

**please help me and suggest me right code to add image with Email ?**

Comment: What is the expanded url value in email message ?

Comment: I want to add image from this URL https://jonathanturley.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/images.png

Answer (score 1):

Creating a user through the User Management page uses the `creationEmail.html` template.  Signing up through the register page uses the `activationEmail.html` template.

You can add images in your JHipster email templates by using a regular image tag:

```
<img src="https://jonathanturley.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/images.png" height="100" width="150" />
```

For example, the image should be displayed in the email like in this screenshot:

[image: Email with Embedded Image]

Comment: I have written this line in my template code but still I don't received email with Image

Comment: Make sure the image allows embeds from an external source.  I copied this code from a working example (changed the URL to match yours)

Comment: I have also try after change new image URL path but still I am not getting Image, I am using Jhipster Following is my whole template code 


Do we need to change any configuration for that ??

Comment: Are you sure you don't have image downloads disabled for your email?  I just tested with your template and I see the image in my email.  I added a screenshot to the answer showing what your template looks like.

Comment: I want exact output that you display in above screen shoot.
How and where can we check that  image downloads disabled or not ??

Comment: I have checked in my Gmail settings,   image downloads is not disabled from my email.

do we required any configuration in Java ?

Comment: I just noticed you are changing the `activationEmail.html`, but when you create a user in User Management it uses the `creationEmail.html` template

Comment: !! Ohhh my god you are right I was changing another file, the right file is creationEmail.html but I was changing in activationEmail.html from last week. Thank you so much, I am student intern and using Jhipster first time 
Thank you so much I got perfect solution from you

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title th:text="#{email.activation.title}">JHipster activation</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/favicon.ico|}" />
    </head>
    <body>
         <img src="https://jonathanturley.files.wordpress.com/2017/06/images.png" height="100" width="150" />

         <p th:text="#{email.activation.greeting(${user.login})}">
            Dear
        </p>
        <p th:text="#{email.activation.text1}">
            Your JHipster account has been created, please click on the URL below to activate it:
        </p>
        <p>
            <a th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/#/activate?key=${user.activationKey}|}"
               th:text="@{|${baseUrl}/#/activate?key=${user.activationKey}|}">Activation Link</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span th:text="#{email.activation.text2}">Regards, </span>
            <br/>
            <em th:text="#{email.signature}">JHipster.</em>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```